# Homography array transformation

Tags: c#, image, 2d, transformation, homography

I am working on a homography method to copy and expand the relevant points from a rectangle area of depthImg array to a new array, but the bottomright points do not change the homographyImg array. Any ideas, suggestions appreciated. Thanks and happy holidays.

```
public short[] depthImg;
public int topleftx = 10;
public int toplefty = 20;
public int toprightx = 300;
public int toprighty = 20;
public int bottomleftx = 30;
public int bottomlefty = 200;
public int bottomrightx = 310;
public int bottomrighty = 220;

short[] homographyImg = new short[320 * 240];
for(int ii = 0; ii < 320 * 240; ii++)
{
    int xx = ii % 320;
    int yy = ii / 320;
    int lx =(topleftx + (bottomleftx - topleftx)*(yy/240));
    int rx =(toprightx + (bottomrightx - toprightx)*(yy/240));
    if (xx < rx & xx > lx)
    {
        int px = 320*(xx-lx)/(rx-lx);
        int ty =(toplefty + (toprighty - toplefty)*(px/320));
        int by =(bottomlefty + (bottomrighty - bottomlefty)*(px/320));
        if (yy > ty & yy < by)
        {
            int pxy = 240*(yy-ty)/(by-ty)*320 + px;
            homographyImg[pxy] = depthImg[ii];
        }
    }
}
```

// I couldn't paste code in the conversation, so I uploaded here. This is a similar array transformation where they modify the corner coordinates to get a correct picture.

```
    for(int yy = 0; yy < newHeight; yy++)
    {
        for(int xx = 0; xx < newWidth; xx++)
        {
            int TLidx = (xx * 2) + yy * 2 * width;
            int TRidx = (xx * 2 + 1) + yy * width * 2;
            int BLidx = (xx * 2) + (yy * 2 + 1) * width;
            int BRidx = (xx * 2 + 1) + (yy * 2 + 1) * width;
            dst[newWidth- xx - 1 + yy * newWidth] = Color32.Lerp(Color32.Lerp(src[BLidx],src[BRidx],.5F),
                                                   Color32.Lerp(src[TLidx],src[TRidx],.5F),.5F);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you mean to use `&` in the `if` statements instead of `&&`?

Comment: i believe & is the good one, since both of the conditions should be true to be in the left-right or later the top-bottom range

Comment: `&` will evaluate both expressions regardless of the truthiness of the first expression. `&&` will evaluate each expression and stop if the first expression is falsely.

Comment: One problem - although I'm not sure if it's *the* problem - is the integer division. You almost always divide `a/b` where b is greater than a. This will return 0. Make the constant a double (e.g. `320.0`) or leave the parentheses away.

Comment: the problem with && that its true even when just the first one is true. Leaving out the parenthesis does help, but the main issue I discovered that the picture representing these points bends parabolic way instead of linear.

Comment: I have found a similar array transformation which modifies the x and y corner points and working, I believe this would be the way, but still not clear